# Setting a required value in Doctrine model

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

Is it possible to set a constraint in a Doctrine model, so that all queries using that model include this requirement? For example, if I have a **Car model** and I want to ensure that all results retrieved using the model have `active = 1` set in the database. I could define this in each individual query, but it seems like there's probably a better way.

Cheers!

Comment: good question! I would like the answer on that as well. In my case I always want users that are still active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take advantage of their amazing pre and post hooks inside the model.

Example:

```
class Model_Car extends Model_Base_Car
{
    public function preDqlSelect(Doctrine_Event $event)
    {
        $event->getQuery()->addWhere("active = ?", 1);
    }
}
```

Although I did not test this, it should work.  I have used the pre and post hooks a lot to make my life easier in the past.  For instance, I had a model that wanted to save the REMOTE_ADDR on each insert and update, so I did the following to make my life easier:

```
class Model_Example extends Model_Base_Example
{
    public function preInsert(Doctrine_Event $event)
    {
        $this->created_ip = $this->_getRemoteIp();
    }

    public function preUpdate(Doctrine_Event $event)
    {
        $this->updated_ip = $this->_getRemoteIp();
    }

    protected function _getRemoteIp()
    {
        return ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    }
}
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in query ->andWhere('active = ?', 1), but if you are tring to do this "tricky way", you can always build your own hydrator.

Answer (score 0):

here is an answer to your question: subclassing the doctrine query object.

http://brentertainment.com/2010/03/03/doctrine_query_extra-extending-the-doctrine-query-object/